# mongoDB $unset each object that matches id in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Here is how my documents look like:

```
{
  id: 123,
  tasks: {
    5f6effae74a3802fe80d02a4: Object
    5f6f289b73cc4e43546733bb: Object
    5f6f28d873cc4e43546733bc: Object
    5f6f291073cc4e43546733bd: Object,
    5f6f291073cc4e43541211cc: Object,
    5f6f291073cc4e43465662eq: Object
  },
  taskIds: [
    5f6effae74a3802fe80d02a4, 
    5f6f289b73cc4e43546733bb, 
    5f6f28d873cc4e43546733bc, 
    5f6f291073cc4e43546733bd
  ]
}
```

I need to delete each object in `tasks` that matches `id` from `taskIds` so I thought about mapping through `taskIds` like this:

```
const tasksDocument = await db.collection.findOne({id: 123})
tasksDocument.taskIds.map(async (id) => await tasksDocument.updateOne({ $unset: { [`tasks.${[id]}`]: "" } }))
```

But I'm wondering if there is cleaner way to do it without mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mongo version 4.2+ you can use [pipelined update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) which allows you to use aggregation operators in an update.

Our strategy will be to convert the object to an array, filter it with the `taskIds` and then converting back to an object, we will achieve this by using operators like `$arrayToObject`, `$objectToArray`, `$filter` and more.

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        'id': 123
    },
    [
        {
            '$set': {
                tasks: {
                    $arrayToObject: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: '$tasks'},
                            as: 'task',
                            cond: {
                                $eq: [
                                    {
                                        $size: {
                                            $setIntersection: [['$$task.k'], '$taskIds']       
                                        }
                                    },
                                    0
                                ] 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

For older Mongo versions you have to split this into 2 calls and do it in code similar to your solution (just having one call to `$unset` instead of multiple).

```
const tasksDocument = await db.collection.findOne({id: 123});
let unsetArr = tasksDocument.taskIds.map(v => `tasks.${v}`);
await db.collection.updateOne({id: 123}, {$unset: unsetArr});
```

Comment: Didn't get a change to try your first solution since I'm on older version but the second one woorks good and looks cleaner, thank you